# SessionsHelper is not defining for all cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ruby on Rails 3.2

My SessionsHelper is working for one of my models but not the other. I cannot figure out the problem. I get his error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `distributor' for #<DistributorsController:0x00000005357c58>):
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:55:in `current_distributor'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:59:in `current_distributor?'
app/controllers/distributors_controller.rb:138:in `correct_distributor'
```

These are all defined in my helper. My ApplicationController has `include SessionsHelper` .What is the problem?

This is part of my helper:

```
def sign_in_distributor(distributor)
    cookies[:remember_token] = distributor.remember_token
    self.current_distributor = distributor
end

def signed_in_distributor?
    !current_distributor.nil?
end

def current_distributor=(distributor)
    @current_distributor = distributor
end 

def current_distributor
    @current_distributor ||= distributor.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end

def current_distributor?(distributor)
    distributor == current_distributor
end

def sign_out_distributor
    self.current_distributor = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

def admin_distributor
    redirect_to(current_distributor) unless current_distributor.admin?
end

def admin_distributor?
    current_distributor.admin?
end
```

This is my controller:

```
class DistributorsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :signed_in_grandstreamer,  only: [:edit, :update, :show, :index]
before_filter :correct_distributor,    only: [:edit, :update, :show, :change_password]
before_filter :admin_distributor,      only: [:index, :new, :edit, :destroy]

def index
@distributors = Distributor.paginate(page: params[:page])

redirect_to root_url
end

def new
if signed_in_distributor?
    redirect_to distributor_path(current_distributor)
elsif signed_in_grandstreamer?
    redirect_to grandstreamer_path(current_grandstreamer)
else    
    @distributor = Distributor.new
end
end

def show
#@distributor = Distributor.find(params[:id])
end 

...skipping some...

private

def signed_in_grandstreamer
    unless signed_in_grandstreamer?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in_grandstreamer?
    end
  end

  def signed_in_distributor
    unless signed_in_distributor?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in_distributor?
    end
  end

  def correct_distributor
    @distributor = Distributor.find(params[:id])
    #@user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @checkuser = Distributor.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(current_distributor) unless current_distributor?(@checkuser) || admin_distributor?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change this helper:

```
def current_distributor
  @current_distributor ||= distributor.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

To:

```
def current_distributor
  @current_distributor ||= Distributor.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

Using `CamelCase` for class name.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
distributor.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
```

To this

```
Distributor.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
```